# replacing object cluster to the new cluster generating the highest SI score

Tags: python, clustered-index

I'm fairly new to python so I hope somebody can help me. we have a list

```
     X         LABELS
[0.85142858]     1
[0.85566274]     0
[0.85364912]     0
[0.81536489]     2
```

i applied k-means to clustering this elemnts with k=3.

The following script calculates max score of SI for each element.

```
for i in range(len(X)):
    s = []
    print("Client", i+1, X[i])

    for label in range(3):
        b = []
        print('S',label, ':')
        a=euclidean_distances(X[[i]], X[kmedoids.medoid_indices_][[label]])
        print('a:', label, a)
        
        for k in range(3):
            if k != label: 
                b.append(euclidean_distances(X[[i]], X[kmedoids.medoid_indices_][[k]]))
                print('b:', k, b)
        bmin=min(b)
        print('miminum b', min(b))
        print('bi-ai', bmin-a)
        print('max{a_i, b_i)', max(a, bmin))
        s.append((bmin-a)/(max(a, bmin)))
        print('SI', s, label)
        print("-------------------")
    max_value = max(s)
    print("SI, max value:", max_value)
    print("***********************")
```

if we assume the following results for element 1, where s0, s1, s2 represent clusters,

how could we assign element 1 to a new cluster with max value (here [0.76259282] for cluster 0) ? so we change cluster for element 1 to 0 instead of 1.

```
element 1 [0.85142858]

S 0 :

SI [ array([[0.76259282]])] 
   
-------------------
S 1 :
  
 SI [array([[-0.76259282]])] 
-------------------
S 2 :
 
SI [ array([[-0.96782002]])] 
-------------------
SI, max value: [[0.76259282]]
```